# HTML/CSS label left: 10px not working

Tags: html, css

I want to align the one label left and the other one right. But not with align-left or align-right. I want to be able to control it with something like right:10px or left:10px. I can't come up with a clean solution.

```css
.Div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 57, 57);
  position: relative;
}

.Div1_1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(60, 172, 66);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1">
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="top:20px; position: relative">Center This</label>
    <br>
    <label style="top:40px; position: relative">Left 10px This</label>
  </div>
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="top:20px; position: relative">Center This</label>
    <br>
    <label style="top:40px; position: relative">Right 10px This</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using margins?  E.g.<label style="top:40px; position: relative; margin-left:10px;">Left 10px This</label> That should work

Comment: I tried it, but nope :) Unless I'm doing something wrong of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With position relative, and left: -10px; to pull left one and right: -10px; to pull right the other one

```css
.Div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 57, 57);
  position: relative;
}

.Div1_1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(60, 172, 66);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1">
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="top:20px; position: relative">Center This</label>
    <br>
    <label style="top:40px; left: -10px; position: relative">Left 10px This</label>
  </div>
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="top:20px; position: relative">Center This</label>
    <br>
    <label style="top:40px; right: -10px; position: relative">Right 10px This</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be much easier with just `padding`:

```css
.Div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 57, 57);
  position: relative;
}

.Div1_1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(60, 172, 66);
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1">
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="text-align: center;">Center This</label>
    <br>
    <label style="text-align: left;">Left 10px This</label>
  </div>
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="text-align: center;">Center This</label>
    <br>
    <label style="text-align: right;">Right 10px This</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Old answer**

You could use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` for this:

```css
.Div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(199, 57, 57);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.Div1_1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(60, 172, 66);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Div1_1 label {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="Div1">
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="">left</label>
    <br>
    <label style="">right</label>
  </div>
  <div class="Div1_1">
    <label style="">left</label>
    <br>
    <label style="">right</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To add space just add some padding like `padding: 0 10px;`.

Comment: Is this aligning them with 10px space? To me it look like 0px, in which case you could just use text-align: left :) I need that 10px space control

Comment: Both your answers definitely work so thank you! I just feel that Alex's answer is easier in line with my problem in this case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```css
.Div1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(199, 57, 57);
    position: relative;
}

.Div1_1 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(60, 172, 66);   
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="Div1">
    <div class="Div1_1">
      <label style="top:20px; position: relative">Center This</label>
      <br>
      <label style="top:40px; position: relative">Left 10px This</label>
    </div>
    <div class="Div1_1" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; left: auto;">
      <label style="top:20px; position: relative">Center This</label>
      <br>
      <label style="top:40px; position: relative">Right 10px This</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe.. But maybe he wants to align one label left and the other right and not the parent divs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not correct :) I need the two labels to align inside their own divs. The one should be against the left side of the green div. The other should be against the right side of the other green div.